# itext7: Div height calculate not correct?

Tags: java, height, itext7

I use `Canvas` to draw `Text` content in rectangle `Div`. However, `Text` content is truncated even though there is still enough space left in `Div`.
The `Div` rectangle has dimension `width: 111` and `height: 78` and my text content is:`CONG TY CO PHAN DICH VU TVAN IAM TEST 999` with font size `16.8`.

Here my sample code:

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
        PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(outputFile), new StampingProperties());
        PdfSignatureAppearance pdfSignatureAppearance = pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance();
        pdfSigner.setFieldName(signatureFieldName);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(30, 20, 111f, 78);
        pdfSignatureAppearance.setPageRect(rect);
        pdfSignatureAppearance.setPageNumber(3);

        String name = "CONG TY CO PHAN DICH VU TVAN IAM TEST 999";

        PdfFormXObject layer2 = pdfSignatureAppearance.getLayer2();
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(layer2, pdfSigner.getDocument());
        Document doc = new Document(pdfSigner.getDocument());
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ARIALUNI.TTF").readAllBytes(), "Identity-H");

        Rectangle signatureRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 111f, 78);
        try (Canvas layoutCanvas = new Canvas(canvas, signatureRect);) {
            Text t = new Text(name);
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph().setFont(font).add(t).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setPadding(0).setMargin(0).setWidth(signatureRect.getWidth()).setMultipliedLeading(0.8f);
            Div lineDiv = new Div();
            lineDiv.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
            paragraph.setKeepTogether(true);
            lineDiv.setPadding(0);
            lineDiv.setMargin(0);
            lineDiv.setKeepTogether(true);
            lineDiv.add(paragraph);

            paragraph.setFontSize(16.8f);// font size
            lineDiv.setFontSize(16.8f);
            this.calculateHeightOfEle(lineDiv, signatureRect.getWidth(), doc.getRenderer());
            lineDiv.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.YELLOW);
            layoutCanvas.add(lineDiv);
            //lineDivHeight calculate is 71.9 and the height of signatureRect is 78, why my text content still truncated?
            float lineDivHeight = this.calculateHeightOfEle(lineDiv, signatureRect.getWidth(), doc.getRenderer());
        }

        //This is for add signature info to PDF
        pdfSignatureAppearance.setReuseAppearance(false);
        IExternalSignature iExternalSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(privateKey, digestAlgorithm, bouncyCastleProvider);
        IExternalDigest iExternalDigest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

        // Sign the document using the detached mode, CMS, or CAdES equivalent.
        pdfSigner.signDetached(iExternalDigest, iExternalSignature, certificateChain, null, null, null, 0, cryptoStandardSubFilter);
```

And `calculateHeightOfEle` method:

```
  public Float calculateHeightOfEle(IElement element, float width, IRenderer rootRender){
        IRenderer eRenderer = element.createRendererSubTree();
        LayoutResult result = eRenderer.setParent(rootRender).layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, new Rectangle(width, 1000))));
        float height =  result.getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getHeight();
        System.out.println("height: " + height);
        return height;
    }
```

The result is:

[image]

And my expect results is:

[image: And my expect results is:]

Why the remain text was not insert to there?
[image]